# Changing NavigationItem’s font

Tags: iphone

I have used this code to change a `NavigationItem`’s title:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"My Name is ABC";
```

How can I change the font size and font as well?

Comment: This is super easy now with UIAppearance, see my answer for example code

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sample Code :

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44);
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8.0];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = @"Sample custom Title With small Fonts ";
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

Comment: That's great... But: If you have a Back button on the left, the view is shifted to the right. Is there anything that can be done to prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: We need to add rightbar pr leftbar button item with nil.. to balance.. If we have rightbarbuttonItem add nil button at leftbarbutton and vice versa...

Answer (score 18):

As of iOS5+, you can use the [UIAppearance protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to change the font of the nav title, here's code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *titleBarAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[UINavigationBar appearance] titleTextAttributes]];
[titleBarAttributes setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleBarAttributes];
```

Answer (score 10):

Since iOS5 you can use the new `titleTextAttributes` property like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
[newAttributes setObject:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:newAttributes];
```

Possible keys are:

```
UITextAttributeFont
UITextAttributeTextColor
UITextAttributeTextShadowColor
UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset
```

Comment: I prefer this solution to the others. I have a `UITableViewController` titled e.g. 'News' that pushes a `UIViewController` within the same `UINavigationController`. When the 2nd view controller is displayed the back-button read 'Back' and not 'News' as you would expect. But with this solution the back-button reads 'News'. Good work, Brabbeldas!

Comment: How to make title font to adjust to the width?

Answer (score 6):

To make the above example centered you have to have the size be only as wide as the text, this should do the trick

```
UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0f];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [@"Lorem Ipsum" sizeWithFont:font].width, 44);
```

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS5, you can do this in 1 line:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f]}];
```

Comment: As a bonus, if you need to adjust the vertical alignment of the custom font, you can add another line as so: 

      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

in AppDelegate.swift

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15)!], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modern Swift 2 solution:

```
let customFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : customFont!]
```

Comment: @jxmorris12 you run in in AppDelegate? works on my app

Answer (score 1):

**//Appearance setup for navigation title font throught application...**

```
let customFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15)
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : customFont!]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found some good answer for this .I think it's similar to the accepted answer however please find it in some more detail.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {  

   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];    

   if (self){
     // this will appear as the title in the navigation bar    
     UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];      
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];         
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];       
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];       
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;      
    label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // change this color      
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;          
    label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PageThreeTitle", @"");       
    [label sizeToFit];    
 }    
 return self;

}
```

For more details, Please refer this [Link](http://iosrider.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/how-to-edit-navigation-bar-title-attribute/)

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName :UIfont(named:"test") ]
```

Comment: You have a single bracket. It is not possible.